# How to play local multiplayer?

Tags: ios, colt-express

I have the iOS version of Colt Express and haven't yet figured out how to do local multiplayer (ie. pass and play). According to [this article](http://www.adweek.com/socialtimes/asmodee-digital-launches-colt-express-on-mobile/647866) local multiplayer is possible, but it is hard to find any other information on the matter.

What I have seen so far is that any option under the local game tab in Classic mode seems to assume I am the only human playing. Whenever I select a character, it throws in 5 computers with me and starts the game. I can't figure out how to make it acknowledge that more than one human is playing the local game. If local multiplayer isn't possible, it would make this the first board game adaptation I've seen that doesn't offer such a feature, so I felt it unusual enough to ask.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Nice first question. I made the game tag for you.

Comment: Perhaps Bluetooth somehow?

Comment: That is a good thought, I wasn't considering local bluetooth play. I've since tried having two iPads with bluetooth next to each other, but the game doesn't seem to have a reaction.

Answer (score 1):

Update: I had further correspondence with support. Their previous response was when they were under the impression I was playing Ticket To Ride. After clearing that up, they instructed me to switch the toggle under Quick Play to Local and hit quick play, but then that's when things got a bit blurry, as per their latest response:

> You just press quick play, wait for a few seconds for the player to be in a lobby, and and then press quick play on the second device. You can also try to go to the chat and add each other to your favorite list. We're aware it's a bit confusing right now, and will introduce a better way to find games online soon.

I'm definitely not seeing a lobby after hitting Quick Play for local play (nor do I ever see a lobby after setting custom options for local play). That, along with the fact that they expect me to use the favorite list (which is an online-specific feature), leads me to believe they may be confused between the local and online modes. I will leave this question open as there may be an update coming to the game soon, which may clear things up.